# New Live tiles don't work in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, live-tile, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-sl-8.1

So when I was watching this video from BUILD I thought it's gonna be easy...

[image]

But I can't seem to get the tile of my WP Silverlight 8.1 app to change by doing the following.

```
    const string xml = "<tile>"
           + "<visual>"
           + "<binding template='TileSquareText01'>"
           + "<text id='1'>testing 123</text>"
           + "</binding>  "
           + "</visual>"
           + "</tile>";

    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    var tileNotification = new TileNotification(xmlDoc);
    TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(tileNotification);
```

Please note I've also created a Windows RunTime Windows Phone 8.1 with exactly the same code and it works just fine.

On msdn, it clearly states that [TileUpdateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdatemanager.Aspx) supports Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. So I don't really know what's missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your manifest, make sure the notification type is set to `WNS`. If you set it to `MPNS`, then you have to use notifications the old way.

More information here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642085(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642085%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh your my savior!! This does the trick! Just to make it clear, the manifest I had to modify is `WMAppManifest.xml`, not the new one generated with 8.1. Thanks!!!